Pandoc, markdown to latex: generate a .bib file when using cite-method biblatex
Context: I write academic documents in Zettlr/markdown, use Zotero and a betterbibtex file to add references in the markdown file, and export this to latex for formatting/publishing. The issue is that I have a single large database of references rather than making project/article specific groups and cannot figure out a time effective method to generate a .bib file for my exports using pandoc.
Exporting markdown to latex through pandoc allows a user to choose biblatex, natbib, or citeproc formats for the in-text references. If using citeproc, a full reference list is generated at the end of the latex document (formatted as bibitems). I expected there would be a similar way to generate a .bib file if using the biblatex format but have not been able to find any working solution. Given the success when using citeproc Pandoc obviously knows how to gather the correct information from the markdown text and betterbibtex reference library.
In some cases the citeproc/bibitem references work fine with journal templates but some do not work. In these instances I need a .bib file and my current workflow falls apart.
I have tried different cite-method options (citeproc, natbib, biblatex), specifying the .bib file in the markdown file (as YAML frontmatter), and converting the bibitem list to biblatex using text2bib (the resulting .bib file did not work).

Can you show us a [mre] of an markdown and bib file which don't work? We can probably then see what's going wrong.

(if you plan on publishing your work in a journal, double check with the publisher if they accept biblatex  - not a lot of journals do)

Does this Q&A help? Otherwise maybe checkout Quarto, which is built on pandoc and offers support for various journal formats.

Thanks for your responses. It seems the issue was not specifying a full path-to-file for the full bibtex library in my YAML frontmatter. The pandoc backend in Zettlr was overriding this with its internal settings so I wasn't getting the expected outcome. Fair to say I feel a bit stupid now.

Glad to hear that the issue has been resolved. Happy writing!
